# node-inspector get nothing in browser

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I am trying to debug with node-inspector on the newly installed iojs 2.3.

I just `npm install -g` the inspector v0.10.2, and type

```
server:~ vince-fan$ node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.10.2
Cannot start the server at 0.0.0.0:8080. Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8080.
There is another process already listening at this address.
Run `node-inspector --web-port={port}` to use a different port.
```

my app is running on port 8080, should I change the web port of inspector? I tried:

```
server:~ vince-fan$ node-inspector --web-port=3000
Node Inspector v0.10.2
Visit http://127.0.0.1:3000/?ws=127.0.0.1:3000&port=5858 to start debugging.
```

When I open the address show above, the browser just give me a big blank page, with nothing, NOTHING showing there.

I tried chrome, safari, nothing works.

anyone has any idea, what's going on?

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for your answer, but I'm sorry it's not the solution, I am trying to post an answer by my self. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, it's because of old version of chrome. once I updated the chrome into the newest version, everything works fine.

probably, this should be notified by node-inspector, I think

Comment: What was the old and the new chrome version?

Comment: the working version is: Version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit). my old version is something version32.xxx, can't remember clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Node inspector will not do anything until there's a process for it to inspect. Try running your node program with the option `--debug` or `--debug-brk` after launching `node-inspector`.